# Adding license badges to generateMarkdown.js

Tags: node.js, markdown

I am enrolled in a coding bootcamp and am working on an assignment where we have to generate a README.md, utilizing node.js

The issue I am stuck on is getting license badges to appear when a license is selected from a list. Once one is selected and the README.md is generated, it will display the license selected, but will not display the badge. Looking up the issue online, it appears all "solutions" I am coming across say the same thing, and that is what I am doing. However, the badge will not appear.

Any and all help is greatly appreciate. Additionally, thank you to any and all that are able to give any of their time to assist me with this. I appreciate you.

```
This is what I have at the top of my generateMarkdown.js file:


function licenseBadge(data) {
  const liceType = data.liceChoice[0];
  let licenseString = " "
  if (liceType === "GNU AGPLv3") {
    licenseString = `[![License: AGPL v3](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-AGPL%20v3-blue.svg)]`
  };
  if (liceType === "GNU GPLv3") {
    licenseString = `![License: GPL v3](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-GPL%20v3-blue.svg)`
  };
  if (liceType === "GNU LGPLv3") {
    licenseString = `![License: LGPL v3](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-LGPL%20v3-blue.svg)`
  };
  if (liceType === "Mozilla Public License 2.0") {
    licenseString = `![License: MPL 2.0](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-MPL%202.0-brightgreen.svg)`
  };
  if (liceType === "Apache License 2.0") {
    licenseString = `![License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache%202.0-blue.svg)`
  };
  if (liceType === "MIT License") {
    licenseString = `![License: MIT License](https://img.shields.io/badge/License-MIT-yellow.svg)`
  };
  return licenseString
};


function generateMarkdown(data) {
  return `# ${data.siteName}



// further down in the code is where the badge is supposed to display.
// NOTE: "data.liceChoice" displays the text for the license chosen. I do not have an issue with this working. "LicenseBadge(data)" is supposed to display the badge but wont for some reason.

${data.liceChoice}. ${licenseBadge(data)}



In the index.js file, below, is the prompt I have for a license to be selected. There are other prompts, but I removed those in here to shorten the code. All of those are working as well, and as I said earlier, it will display the text of the License chosen too, just not the badge.


function init() {

    const inquirer = require('inquirer');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const generate = require('./utils/generateMarkdown.js');
    const path = require('path');

    inquirer
        .prompt([
            {
                type: `rawlist`,
                name: `liceChoice`,
                message: `What kind of licensing do you want applied to your project? NOTE: Use the Up/Down arrows to navigate through the list, type the number option then press "Enter", or highlight your selection and press "Enter", to select your choice.`,
                choices: [`GNU AGPLv3`, `GNU GPLv3`, `GNU LGPLv3`, `Mozilla Public License 2.0`, `Apache License 2.0`, `MIT License`],
            },
])
        .then((response) => {
            return fs.writeFileSync(path.join (process.cwd(), "READMEtest.md"), generate(response));
        });
}

init();
```